# Convert Dimension to int in Java?

Tags: java

absolute java noob here. I was messing with some code and wondering if there is a way to convert a Dimension value to an integer or string.

I was using this line

```
int i = (int) frame.getSize();
```

to get the size of a window but it cannot convert a dimension to int. Any help?

Comment: Hint: size has two dimensions - width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "convert" a `Dimension` to `int`, because it is something different. It is meant to store information about a rectangle.

You can calculate the area of the rectangle:

```
double size = frame.getSize().getHeight() * frame.getSize().getWidth();
```

Of cause you can also store the information as a string:

```
String sizeStr = frame.getSize().getHeight() +" X " + frame.getSize().getWidth();
```

Now you could store the Dimension (but you would need to split the string again, to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

> frame.getSize();

This is returning an [Dimension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) object. You cannot convert and object to primitive type.

The Dimension have two attribute, height and width. You can use getter methods to access them.

**double getHeight() :** Returns the height of this Dimension in double precision.

**double    getWidth() :** Returns the width of this Dimension in double precision.

The size of the Window can be calculated using `Height` and `Width`. As both are of `double` type, you need to store the size in `double` type.

```
Dimension dim = frame.getSize();
double size = dim.getHeight() * dim.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an `Dimension` to a primitive. What you could do, however, is use the access methods, such as `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` to calculate it:

```
// No need to explicitly cast, Java will do that automatically
// (although it will issue a warning on lost precision)
int size = frame.getHeight() * frame.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

The dimension object instantiated as follows;

```
Dimension dim = new Dimension(100, 50);
```

That means, there are two factors, which you should think of, these are height and weight.

If you simply say,

```
int i = (int) frame.getSize();
```

it is like;

```
int i = (int) height, weight.
```

Briefly, you cannot assign two values to one variable. You should make some calculation(s) to have one value from these two values.